# Какие есть способы добавить фоновую картинку в 2Д игре в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

Так как я новичок, мне дали тестовое задание, есть игра в которой некоторые обьекты генерируются вне `canvas` - a, но отображаются в игре и при этом они находятся выше камеры по иерархий, ниже картинка.
Но добавленный мной бэкграунд не отображается. Подскажите возможности добавить бэкграун.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте отдельную камеру на сцену, которая будет рисовать только бэкграунд. Но при этом, если у вас есть еще камеры на сцене, настройте их так, чтобы они перерисовывали ваш бэкграунд, а именно посмотрите в сторону настроек `Culling Mask` и `Background`

А также настройте ваш `Canvas`, чтобы он рисовался в режиме либо `Screen Space - Camera` либо `World Space`

Comment: Не знаю на сколько корректно, но я использовал 2 `canvas` - a, что на это можете прокоментировать, стойт ли ? и правильно ли это ?

Comment: @IDontLikeBugs по идее, что 2 нанваса, что 2 камеры - примерно одно и тоже по производительности. Решение с 2 камерами - довольно стандартное для такой ситуации, потому что не требует никаких манипуляций (порядок отрисовки других элементов и их количество не будет влиять на отрисовку бэка). 2 канваса имхо тоже нормально, это легче и удобней, чем делать все в одном, а потом писать скрипты, чтобы все вставало на место после добавления новых элементов. Использование нескольких канвасов - нормальная практика, например, когда UI "встраивается" в окружение мира